# $\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\leq x(t)(a-bx(t))$ $\implies$ $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \sup $ $x(t)\leq \frac{a}{b}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If $$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\leq x(t)\big(a-bx(t)\big),$$ then prove that

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \sup x(t)\leq \frac{a}{b},$$ 
where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Comment: Are there additional conditions, like $a,b>0$, $x(t)\ge 0$ or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x(t)>0$, then divide by $x^2$ like with a Bernoulli equation, and set $u=1/x$ to find
$$
-u'=\frac{x'}{x^2}\le au-b
$$
Now use the integrating factor $e^{at}$ to find
$$
be^{at}\le (e^{at}u)'\implies \frac{b}{a}(e^{at_2}-e^{at_1})\le e^{at_2}u(t_2)-e^{at_1}u(t_1)
$$
and try to find conclusions for $t_2\to\infty$.